# Computing Minima for degree 8 polynomial

Tags: polynomials, maxima-minima

Is there any better method than derivative or trial and error to calculate minima of $$f(x)=x^8-8x^6+19x^4-12x^3+14x^2-8x+9$$

The minima occurs at $x=2$ and $f(2)=1$

We were given option too $-1,9,6,1$ if that helps

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By splitting conveniently the terms (by [completing squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square) from left to right)  we obtain
$$\begin{align}f(x)&=x^8-8x^6+(16+3)x^4-12x^3+(12+2)x^2-8x+(8+1)
\\&=(x^8-8x^6+16x^4)+(3x^4-12x^3+12x^2)+(2x^2-8x+8)+1\\
&=x^4(x^2-4)^2+3x^2(x-2)^2+2(x-2)^2+1\geq 1=f(2).\end{align}$$

Comment: How did you find this?

Comment: I revised my answer. Maybe this one is more interesting

Comment: This look good to me (+1). The OP may need another method for his homework, but fortunately he is only here unter a False Name.

Comment: @lhf Thanks for your comment. It forced me to improve my answer.

Comment: Very nice answer! (+1)

Comment: @DietrichBurde Damn, you caught me.

Comment: Why did you chose 2 to complete the sqaure though? Was it because it automatically came with the $x^8$ and $x^6$ terms?

Comment: No. In order to show that a polynomial $P(x)$ has a minimum at $x_0$ one can try  to show that $P(x)$ can be written as sum of squares $+P(x_0)$ where each square is zero at $x_0$. I think that this 8-degree polynomial has been constructed just in this way from my last line to the first one.